# How to stop turtle movement when two turtles are in proximity of each other?

Tags: python

I'm making a game when the user has to move the car to dodge obstacles, Everything working except I can't get the game to and end. My goal is to end the game when the block hits the turtle.

The issue is I can't get the game to detect the turtles to detect their proximity and the exit or quit command doesn't work. Also I don't think the code pasted properly so adjust the indents if it doesn't work.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
import sys

#initialize turtles
turtle = trtl.Turtle(shape = "turtle")
block = trtl.Turtle(shape = "square")
drawer = trtl.Turtle()
blockList = []
wn = trtl.Screen()

#game configuration
turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(0,-150)
drawer.pu()
drawer.goto(0,-160)
drawer.pd()
drawer.pensize(10)
drawer.pencolor("blue")
drawer.forward(180)
drawer.left(90)
drawer.forward(300)
drawer.left(90)
drawer.forward(350)
drawer.left(90)
drawer.forward(300)
drawer.left(90)
drawer.forward(180)
drawer.hideturtle()

def turtleRight():
 turtle.setheading(0)
 turtle.pu()
 turtle.forward(15)

def turtleLeft():
 turtle.setheading(180)
 turtle.pu()
 turtle.forward(15)

 #actions
 wn.onkeypress(turtleRight, 'Right')
 wn.onkeypress(turtleLeft, 'Left')
 wn.listen()

 for i in range(5):
 app = block
 blockList.append(app)

 #functions
 def draw_blocks(index):
  blockList[index].penup()
  blockList[index].shape("square")
  wn.tracer(False)
  blockList[index].setx(rand.randint(-150,150))
  blockList[index].sety(rand.randint(0,125))
  blockList[index].showturtle()
  wn.tracer(True)
  wn.update()

 def drop_block(index):
  blockList[index].penup()
  blockList[index].clear()
  blockList[index].speed(2)
  blockList[index].sety(-150)
  blockList[index].hideturtle()
  draw_blocks(index)
  xDistance = abs(turtle.xcor()-block.xcor())
  yDistance = abs(turtle.ycor()-block.ycor())
  if (xDistance < 20 and yDistance < 20):
   sys.exit()
  else:
   drop_block(i)

 for i in range(5):
 drop_block(i)

 wn.mainloop()
 trtl.done()
```

Can anyone help..!?

Comment: Hmm. You would probably need to calculate the distance _before_ you make the turtle move. If the movement value would cause the turtle to get into proximity, then change the value to be the distance to the proximity where the turtle should stop. That should give you the effect you want.

Comment: So move the if/else statements further up?

Comment: In short, before the turtle moves, you want to calculate what the distance _would_ be after the move. You may have to refactor things a bit to achieve this.

Comment: Can you fix the code that I posted? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Actually, I take that all back. There is a different problem....The `yDistance` always seems to be very high. So the calculation is happening at the wrong time, it seems. Almost as if it's calculated before it falls? I will investigate further and formulate an answer soon.

Comment: Thank You this fixed my problem. Happy New Years!

Comment: Cheers. If this fully answered your question, please feel free to accept/vote on my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-drawing the block and thus resetting its position before you're testing the distance.

Alter the function like so:

```py
def drop_block(index):
  blockList[index].penup()
  blockList[index].clear()
  blockList[index].speed(2)
  blockList[index].sety(-150)
  blockList[index].hideturtle()
  xDistance = abs(turtle.xcor()-block.xcor())
  yDistance = abs(turtle.ycor()-block.ycor())
  print(xDistance, yDistance)
  if (xDistance < 20 and yDistance < 20):
   sys.exit()
  else:  # redraw blocks _after_ calculating distance
   draw_blocks(index)
   drop_block(i)
```